# How to add a custom pointer for tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

```
// @name         Master's Watermark Script
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Editable Watermark for Gota.io
// @author       Master
// @match        https://gota.io/web/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

function addStyleSheet(style){
  var getHead = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
  var cssNode = window.document.createElement( 'style' );
  var elementStyle= getHead.appendChild(cssNode);
  elementStyle.innerHTML = style;
  return elementStyle;
}

//Custom Crosshair
GM_addStyle ('body {cursor: url(https://ani.cursors-4u.net/cursors/cur-13/cur1160.png)16 16, auto;}');
GM_addStyle ('body {cursor: url(https://ani.cursors-4u.net/cursors/cur-13/cur1160.png)16 16, pointer;}');
```

Hey guys! I'm really new to coding I am coding in tampermonkey I really don't know about stuff which makes me kinda stupid I wanted to add a pointer to the cursor a custom cursor but I added this code but still It wont work for some reason it still sticks with the normal pointer
`GM_addStyle ('body {cursor: url(https://ani.cursors-4u.net/cursors/cur-13/cur1160.png)16 16, pointer;}');`

Answer (score 0):

- i think that you should to add the style before append it for example

```
function addStyleSheet(style){
  var getHead = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
  var cssNode = document.createElement( 'style' );
  cssNode.innerHTML = style;
  var elementStyle= getHead.appendChild(cssNode);
  return elementStyle;
}
```

- anyway i think that you don't need to return the elementStyle variable because you are already appended it and you won't use it for another thing
- you can use another method

```
function createElement(elem, content, css) {
  let newElem = document.createElement(elem);
  newElem.innerHTML = content;
  newElem.style.cssText = css;
  return newElem;
}
document.body.append(createElement('div', 'content', 'background-color: red'))
```

- or if you wants to just set new style to exist element you can use this function

```
function setStyle(id, style) {
   let elem = document.getElementById(id);
   elem.style.cssText = style;
}
setStyle('elem', 'background-color: red');
```

- also with tampermonkey i suggest to add your code inside `setTimeout()` because some web pages need some time to load the content

Comment: what does this 'div', 'content', 'background-color: red' do can u make an sample out of that?

Comment: you can add `cursor: pointer` instead or use any css properties